# Registry pattern evaluated a compil-time

Tags: c++, constexpr

## EDIT

I got somewhat of a solution and a definite answer
After exploring bit i can conclude that :

- It is not possible to count the occurence of something accross different translation units and use it as a constexpr value because translation units should be independant.
- Registry pattern at compil time is possible but its size must be predetermined (no dynamic allocation). This a big setback for cleaner code
- Registry at compil time might not be a good idea if order might matter (inside a registry or between multiple registries)

Chosen Solution :
static registry that rely on static instantiation to store a vector of `std::function<void(RealRegistryHere &)>`.

You can then control whenever you will want to execute the lambdas to do the actual registration process.

Exemple : (static registration method is called in the constructor of Registerer)

In SomeFactory.cpp :

```c++
static Registerer registerer([](ComponentRegistry &registry, PoolManager &manager) {
    registry.registerType<SomeComponent>(new SomeFactory(manager));
});
```

This way we can register thing from the place they are defined, avoiding the need of a grouped registration.

---

I am struggling designing a registry evaluated a compil time to register all factories of a parent object and i couldn't find resources online about that topic.

### Some background

I am working on a little game engine project from scratch as a learning experience (no goal to do an actual game here). I am mostly following the classical ECS pattern and use de c++20 standard

### The problem

To handle the entities i have defined them as an id (size_t, it's just an index) and a std::bitset in which every bits tells us if the entity has corresponding component.

You can then instanciate / test easily with bitmasks :

```c++
std::bitset<FACTORY_COUNT> entity = create_entity(COMPONENT_POSITION | COMPONENT_IMAGE);


if (entity & COMPONENT_POSITION) {
  //do something...
}
```

Where COMPONENT_POSITION and COMPONENT_IMAGE can be defined as an enumeration:

```c++
enum Components {
  COMPONENT_IMAGE = 1 << 0,
  COMPONENT_POSITION 1 << 1,
  COMPONENT_SOMETHING 1 << 2
  //and do on...
}
```

Although this way you can get a total number of components at compil-time I don't like this solution because it's not flexible. You need to define all your components in an enumeration in the same code file increasing dependency. The same problem will arise if there is a need to write a method registerFactories that would register them one by one (still it is much better than the enum).

Considering that all components and their associated factory is known at compile-time it should be possible to make something akin to a registry which would be aware of how many factories to build Component object derived exists at compile-time.
It then could return the number as a constexpr value which could be used to instanciate std::biset.

Another upgrade that could be done at compil time would be replacing the registered key of a component (obviously not an enumeration, i was think of a string that you can access by calling a static method of the derived component class) by its bitmask value so that runtime only do bitwise calculus concerning entities, every thing else is systems and observers.

I tried a few thing through template with static classes method and a custom map (no dynamic allocation) with no avails.

I could provide a few code examples but I'm not sure if they would be relevant, just tell me if you think it would.

Is there anyway to achieve something similar to a registry while being evaluated at compile-time?

Thank you for your time and dont hesitate if you have any suggestions!

Comment: what is your question? First paragraph sounds like you are looking for online resources, but thats offtopic.

Comment: btw "no goal to do an actual game here" I think this is a mistake. You cannot develop a working well designed game engine without also developing a game.

Comment: I first tried to find related resources but haven't found anything, then kept trying by myself without success so i finally asked the question here as it might be a little to precise.

Comment: but there is no question in your post

Comment: I am planning to do one, but not on this project, this one is to get back in c++ & do a quick revision of ECS precepts. When going for the actual game i'll do a big refactor  but i prefer trying things out before + i have a lot of free time :)

Comment: Indeed must be an error i edited it

Comment: Not sure – bust by reading it the `bitset` as some kind of smell to me – maybe unjustified, but to be honest I've far too little insight in what your engine actually should look like...

Comment: What do you mean by some kind of smell?
To make it simple ECS stands for entity-component-system:
- entities are a group of components defined by a bitset
- components holds all the data but no logic (except things like mutex)
- systems holds all the logic and update the components data, and you can run them independently on threads if you wish to.

The bitset here is kind of the DNA of the entity, defining which component it have.
Systems will then be executed on entities which bitset machtes the need of a system.

e.g: 'PhysicsSystem' matches 'POSITION_COMPONENT | HITBOX_COMPONENT'

Comment: Not sure what Aconcagua means but to me its a desgin smell to hand the `bitset` to the caller. I think it should rather be an implementation detail. A caller should not be able to set individual bits, they should get a transparent handle that implements the required interface, rather then getting direct access to the individual bits

Comment: though, same issue for me, its difficult to discuss the design without more information on the use cases

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I can summarize the concept(s) you are trying to investigate with this prototype project.

The game engine will have entities each of which have some number of components which the engine will represent as a `std::bitset`. The entities and components are all known at compile time, so you would like a way to compute the number of components as a `constexpr` to use when defining the `std::bitset`.

Is that the question (or one of the questions) you are asking?

If so, I think the options are limited. Using an enumeration is simple and effective, but yes, it becomes a central point of dependency.

I do not think it is possible to use any type of registry to produce a compile-time constant. Registries typically rely on performing a runtime action when a type is statically created -- this is obviously too late in the process for producing a compile-time result.

Of course, you could create a `std::tuple` of the types and then easily count the number of types at compile-time. This has the opposite dependency profile as the enumeration which I think is beneficial. Every component has to depend on the enumeration, but the `std::tuple` definition would depend on the component type declarations and the components would not depend at all on the `std::tuple`.

Comment: The conclusion (as edited in the first message) is that this is not possible. Either #define COMPONENT_COUNT and you can do a constexpr registry but you have to group the registration. Only runtime allow enough flexibility.